How do i get 8 hours deep sleep?
I am trying to improve my sleep, most of the time I get about 6 hours and half to 6 hours and 50 minutes of sleep, sometimes I only sleep 4-5 hours, and sometimes 8 hours
I have problem with having deep sleep, which is basically sleeping 8 hours in row without waking up, for some reasons I just wake up for no reason at the middle of the night, or because I have to really pee.
How do I consistently sleep 8 hours on deep sleep, I try to turn off all devices half an hour before sleep, I try to sleep between 12:30 am to 1:00 am everyday.
Today I woke up at 3:30 am, closed my eyes until 5:20 am, however, it didn't feel like I was really asleep (what I mean is that during those 2 hours, I didn't feel like I was sleeping while my eyes were closed, basically, I was conscious)
the day before I slept 5 hours only, and the day before that I slept about 6 hours and 40-ish minutes or so.
On a side note, I have made a blood test in February, and magnesium is in the range, zinc is borderline, but I suspect that zinc has big effect on sleeping the same way magnesium does.
UPDATE:
I don't take any caffeine at all.
room temperature is cool because I open the window
room is dark when i sleep, no light at all.

What is your caffeine intake like? How close to bed do you eat? How dark is your room when you try to sleep? What is the room temp when you sleep? There are several, several questions that  need to be answered before it comes down to blood test to figure out zinc or magnesium that would be affecting your sleep.

@DamiyenGee Thanks Damiyen, I updated my question.

First off, it is normal to wake up after every sleep cycle (approx. 90 minutes). Most people just won't realise that as they are back to sleep fast and the brain discards the memory as irrelevant. That being said, deep sleep is one phase of your sleep cycle. And you cannot be in deep sleep 8 hours straight.
Apart from what has already been mentioned, there are some additional things that help with sleep:

Expose yourself to natural daylight as much as possible. The hormone that makes you sleepy is produced as a reaction to UV light meeting receptors in the eye. Since e.g. the windows of cars and many office buildings feature UV filters these days, this and wearing sunglasses all the time can be detrimental to your sleep.
Do not work out, eat, or drink great amounts in the 3-4 hours before going to sleep. When your body is occupied with managing the input (or your bladder is full), sleeping is hard.
Should you wake up, never (!) switch the light on (even for going to the toilet) or take a look at your phone. Light input literally kills off your sleep hormones so that your will have a harder time getting back to sleep.
May sound like it should not even have to be mentioned but reducing stress and learning meditation or body scan / relaxation techniques helps as well.
Last but not least, the more you make a fuss and think about your sleep, the harder it will be to fall asleep.


+1 For mentioning meditation or body scan/ relaxation here! I work with people who often have problems with sleep and those techniques really help a lot in most of the cases.
